# Creating a dense vector from multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating an index from some data that looks like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"a":1.00000000000000000000,"b":0.07209573847051955633,"c":0E-24,"d":0.98259259259259259259 ...}
```

How do I create a dense vector from multiple fields ie. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc., so that I can perform a cosine similarity search?

Can I do it after uploading the data to ES or is transforming the data before upload the only option?